# Could not find Boost libraries or Version is too old

Tags: building, monero-core

I tried to compile Monero Core for Debian platform, but I got this error

```
Could not find Boost libraries, please make sure you have installed
Boost or libboost-all-dev (1.58) or the equivalent.
```

What should I do in order to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Debian and Ubuntu platforms the highest available version of Boost is 1.55 . You have to download 1.58 sources and install it.

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.58.0/boost_1_58_0.tar.gz
```

decompress the archive

```
tar -xf boost_1_58_0.tar.gz
```

then navigate to the folder

```
cd boost_1_58_0
```

and run the bash script for configuration of building Boost

```
./bootstrap.sh
```

Finally compile!

```
./b2
```

Install by `sudo ./bjam install`

After installing new Boost version, execute on Monero source code folder:

```
make clean
make
```